# Count occurrences of combinations of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, window-functions

I have daily time series (actually business days) for different companies and I work with PostgreSQL. There is also an indicator variable (called flag) taking the value 0 most of the time, and 1 on some rare event days. If the indicator variable takes the value 1 for a company, I want to further investigate the entries from two days before to one day after that event for the corresponding company. Let me refer to that as [-2,1] window with the event day being day 0.

I am using the following query

```
CREATE TABLE test AS
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *
        , MAX(flag) OVER(PARTITION BY company ORDER BY day
                         ROWS BETWEEN 1 preceding AND 2 following) Lead1
   FROM mytable)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE Lead1 = 1 
ORDER BY day,company
```

The query takes the entries ranging from 2 days before the event to one day after the event, for the company experiencing the event. 
The query does that for all events.

This is a small section of the resulting table.

```
day              company    flag     
2012-01-23       A          0        
2012-01-24       A          0         
2012-01-25       A          1         
2012-01-25       B          0         
2012-01-26       A          0         
2012-01-26       B          0        
2012-01-27       B          1        
2012-01-30       B          0        
2013-01-10       A          0        
2013-01-11       A          0              
2013-01-14       A          1
```

Now I want to do further calculations for every [-2,1] window separately. So I need a variable that allows me to identify each [-2,1] window. The idea is that I count the number of windows for every company with the variable "occur", so that in further calculations I can use the clause

```
    GROUP BY company, occur
```

Therefore my desired output looks like that:

```
day              company    flag     occur
2012-01-23       A          0        1
2012-01-24       A          0        1 
2012-01-25       A          1        1 
2012-01-25       B          0        1 
2012-01-26       A          0        1 
2012-01-26       B          0        1
2012-01-27       B          1        1
2012-01-30       B          0        1
2013-01-10       A          0        2
2013-01-11       A          0        2
2013-01-14       A          1        2
```

In the example, the company B only occurs once (occur = 1). But the company A occurs two times. For the first time from 2012-01-23 to 2012-01-26. And for the second time from 2013-01-10 to 2013-01-14. The second time range of company A does not consist of all four days surrounding the event day (-2,-1,0,1) since the company leaves the dataset before the end of that time range.

As I said I am working with business days. I don't care for holidays, I have data from monday to friday. Earlier I wrote the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addbusinessdays(date, integer)
  RETURNS date AS
$BODY$ 
WITH alldates AS (
    SELECT i,
    $1 + (i * CASE WHEN $2 < 0 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END) AS date
    FROM generate_series(0,(ABS($2) + 5)*2) i
),
days AS (
    SELECT i, date, EXTRACT('dow' FROM date) AS dow
    FROM alldates
),
businessdays AS (
    SELECT i, date, d.dow FROM days d
    WHERE d.dow BETWEEN 1 AND 5
    ORDER BY i
)

-- adding business days to a date --
SELECT date FROM businessdays WHERE
        CASE WHEN $2 > 0 THEN date >=$1 WHEN $2 < 0
             THEN date <=$1 ELSE date =$1 END
    LIMIT 1
    offset ABS($2)
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE;
```

It can add/substract business days from a given date and works like that:

```
    select * from addbusinessdays('2013-01-14',-2)
```

delivers the result 2013-01-10. So in Jakub's approach we can change the second and third last line to

```
      w.day BETWEEN addbusinessdays(t1.day, -2) AND addbusinessdays(t1.day, 1)
```

and can deal with the business days.

Comment: How do you 'define' a window?

Comment: By window I mean the days surrounding the day where flag = 1 for a given company. So considering the flag day to be day 0, the [-2,1] window is the time period ranging from 2 days before until 1 day after the flag day. @MarkLaREZZA

Comment: So there are always 4 days in a window?

Comment: Yes theoretically the window is always 4 days, but it is possible that for some companies I don't have data on all 4 days. @MarkLaREZZA

Comment: Got it - thanks. I think I misread the post initially.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you think of a solution? @MarkLaREZZA

Comment: Well, I tried a couple of things and they didn't work, but I am going to keep trying. Do these flags/windows happen once a year? If so, the query could possibly use the Year() to count by, but I have a good feeling that's not the case.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. And yes you're right, they can happen anytime. The only thing that is ensured, is that two subsequent windows of the same firm can never overlap. @MarkLaREZZA

Comment: What is the flag day for `2013-01-13 A` window?

Comment: It is the day where flag = 1 for company A in the second last row of the table. But you're right anyway, I have chosen unwise example dates, I updated my question. @JakubKania

Comment: Feel free to ask me if anything remained unclear. Do you know how it can be done? @JakubKania

Comment: @user3319629 I still don't understand why `2013-01-10 A`  is 2. It seems to be oustide of range of the second window.

Comment: The flag day is on 2013-01-14. 2013-01-10 is two business days before that. I do not have observation on weekends and only care for business days. Sorry that I was not precise enough. @JakubKania

Comment: Please phrase a proper, complete **question**. You talk a lot about windows, but it's hard to pin down what you want exactly. Your second data set doesn't seem to be the desired result. What would it look like? And how is the time frame for the query defined?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added the question to be more precise concerning my problem and my desired output. @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: After reading your previous questions, I finally understand what you are after - or so I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Function

While using the function `addbusinessdays()`, consider this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addbusinessdays(date, integer)
  RETURNS date AS
$func$ 
SELECT day
FROM  (
    SELECT i, $1 + i * sign($2)::int AS day
    FROM   generate_series(0, ((abs($2) * 7) / 5) + 3) i
    ) sub
WHERE  EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM day) < 6  -- truncate weekend
ORDER  BY i
OFFSET abs($2)
LIMIT  1
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

#### Major points

- Never quote the language name `sql`. It's an identifier, not a string.
- Why was the function `VOLATILE`? Make it `IMMUTABLE` for better performance in repeated use and more options (like using it in a functional index).
- `(ABS($2) + 5)*2)` is way too much padding. Replace with `((abs($2) * 7) / 5) + 3)`.
- Multiple levels of CTEs were useless cruft.
- `ORDER BY` in last CTE was useless, too.
- As mentioned in my previous answer, [`extract(`ISODOW `FROM ...)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACTUse%20it%20in%20your%20UPDATE:) is more convenient to truncate weekends.

### Query

That said, I wouldn't use above function for this query at all. Build a complete grid of relevant days once instead of calculating the range of days for every single row.

Based on this assertion in a comment (should be in the question, really!):

> two subsequent windows of the same firm can never overlap.

```
WITH range AS (              -- only with flag
   SELECT company
        , min(day) - 2 AS r_start
        , max(day) + 1 AS r_stop
   FROM   tbl t 
   WHERE  flag <> 0
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
, grid AS (
   SELECT company, day::date
   FROM   range r
         ,generate_series(r.r_start, r.r_stop, interval '1d') d(day)
   WHERE  extract('ISODOW' FROM d.day) < 6
   )
SELECT *, sum(flag) OVER(PARTITION BY company ORDER BY day
                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                         AND 2 following) AS window_nr
FROM  (
   SELECT t.*, max(t.flag) OVER(PARTITION BY g.company ORDER BY g.day
                           ROWS BETWEEN 1 preceding
                           AND 2 following) in_window
   FROM   grid     g
   LEFT   JOIN tbl t USING (company, day)
   ) sub
WHERE  in_window > 0      -- only rows in [-2,1] window
AND    day IS NOT NULL    -- exclude missing days in [-2,1] window
ORDER  BY company, day;
```

#### How?

- Build a grid of all business days: CTE `grid`.
- To keep the grid to its smallest possible size, extract minimum and maximum (plus buffer) day per company: CTE `range`.
- `LEFT JOIN` actual rows to it. Now the frames for ensuing window functions works with static numbers.
- To get distinct numbers per flag and company (`window_nr`), just count flags from the start of the grid (taking buffers into account).
- Only keep days inside your [-2,1] windows (`in_window > 0`).
- Only keep days with actual rows in the table.

Voilá.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a4982/2)

Comment: Fantastic answer, it works perfectly! Thanks again for your help and for your explanations to help me understand it better! It is very generous that you share your knowledge @ErwinBrandstetter

Answer (score 1):

Basically the strategy is to first enumarate the flag days and then join others with them:

```
WITH windows AS(
SELECT t1.day
       ,t1.company
       ,rank() OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY day) as rank
FROM table1 t1
WHERE flag =1)

SELECT t1.day
      ,t1.company
      ,t1.flag
      ,w.rank
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN windows AS w
ON
  t1.company = w.company
  AND
  w.day BETWEEN 
 t1.day - interval '2 day' AND t1.day + interval '1 day'
ORDER BY t1.day, t1.company;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3d178/11).

However there is a problem with work days as those can mean whatever (do holidays count?).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and excuse me for being not precise enough. I don't care for holidays, in my dataset are entries from monday to friday. I edited the question to be more precise concerning the business days. @JakubKania